# CatBoost and LightGBM: training a classifier with weights

Tags: lightgbm, catboost

I am training a (binary) classifier with sample weights. The distribution of the weights is skewed. While half of the training samples have weight 1, the other half has weights greater than 1 (300 - 25000). Additionally, the weights correlate with the label: label = 0 -> weight = 1 and label = 1 -> weight > 1.

The CatBoost classifier does a good job accounting for these weights, but LightGBM does not. More specifically, the Catboost classifier is well calibrated, while the LightGBM classifier learns to predict a probability greater than 0.9 for having label = 1 for almost every sample.

Is there any special treatment of weights in the CatBoost algorithm (e.g. normalising the weights before training)?

Any other idea why the two algorithms behave differently when training with sample weights?